# Lan on PC with a Windows 10 computer for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I used to be able to simply create a LAN game on my computer (which was using Windows 7), and my wife could find it on her computer in multiplayer and join me. We have upgraded our computers to Windows 10 and now we can't find each other anymore. No firewall option can change it, and yes I am aware of the server making stuff but I simply want a LAN game which works. Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 has a slightly different network setup to previous versions.
You may need to join the same workgroup, you can find information on that [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/join-or-create-a-workgroup).

Another possibility is that it is permissions based. Have a look at what security settings you have set.

It might also be worth looking [here](https://superuser.com/questions/956124/windows-10-network-drive-permissions-problems).